# Cannot get camera image

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, camera

I created a simple app supposes to show a live image to a view from iPhone camera modifying this tutorial which is written in Swift2 into Swift3.

I use Xcode 8.1 and run the app on iPhone 6 with iOS version of 9.3.4
my Xcode deployment target setting is 9.1

When I run the app, the code complete without an error but camera image is not showing. The app doesn't even show permission alert for using camera.

What am I doing wrong?

Following is my complete code.

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    // MARK: UI

    let cameraView: UIView = {
        let v = UIView()
        v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return v
    }()

    // MARK: System

    var captureSession = AVCaptureSession()
    var sessionOutput  = AVCaptureStillImageOutput()
    var previewLayer   = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setupSubviews()
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        cameraSetup()
    }

    func setupSubviews() {
        view.addSubview( cameraView )

        cameraView.backgroundColor = UIColor.orange
        cameraView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        cameraView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
        cameraView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200).isActive = true
        cameraView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200).isActive = true

    }

    func cameraSetup() {

        print("**** Start Camera Setup ****")

        let devices = AVCaptureDevice.devices(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo)! as! [AVCaptureDevice]
        for device in devices {
            if device.position == .front {
                print("Front")

                do {
                    let input = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: device)

                    if captureSession.canAddInput(input) {
                        captureSession.addInput(input)
                        sessionOutput.outputSettings = [AVVideoCodecKey: AVVideoCodecJPEG]

                        print("Input added")

                        if captureSession.canAddOutput(sessionOutput) {
                            captureSession.addOutput(sessionOutput)
                            captureSession.startRunning()

                            previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession)
                            previewLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill
                            previewLayer.connection.videoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientation.portrait
                            cameraView.layer.addSublayer(previewLayer)
                            previewLayer.position = CGPoint(x: self.cameraView.frame.width / 2, y: self.cameraView.frame.height / 2)
                            previewLayer.bounds = cameraView.frame

                            print("Output added")
                        }
                    }


                } catch {
                    print("Error")
                }

            }
        }

        print("**** Finish Camera Setup ****")
    }

}
```

Comment: Delete the app from your Device and re install it in your device, if you added camera permission then it definitely ask. **Remember** simulator does not have  camera, so use iPhone or ipad to check code.

Comment: did you added `Privacy - Camera usage description` into your plist?